# How does Google Adsense get the topic of the page?

Tags: adsense

I have built a web application.

Once you logged in, two Google Adsense advs are shown.

The problem is that the product advertised is pretty much always the same even if my webapp is a task/project management tool and I guess there are a lot of products out there that are doing marketing with Google Adsense.

Google can't access the private page of my users (and I don't want that) so I thought it was just spidering the login page but, checking the web server access log, it seems Google is not trying to read any page.

I guess probably it uses some sort of cache.

My final goal is just to have more variety of products advertised my Google Adsense.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Not until recently did Adsense allow the AdSense crawler to access pages that are behind a login. And even now, you have to manually opt-in.
If you don't, Google's crawler will access those pages only once to determine relevant content, and then cache.

You can however, adjust your settings and allow it to go behind protected pages by entering by entering an authentication URL and set parameters for the crawler to determine content to target ads more regularly.

At this point, Google recommends you take three steps to get things set up properly:

1. Enter an authentication rule: Specify an authentication URL and a set of parameters that will allow Google's web crawlers to access your content.
2. Verify your site ownership using Google Webmaster Tools: We will direct you to Google Webmaster Tools, where you can verify that you own the site by uploading a file to it or changing the META tag of a file.
3. View your improved ad targeting: When your authentication rule is verified, you should see better ad targeting on your pages. You can check the status of your authentication rules at any time.

Answer (score 0):

It will gather information from pages on your site that it can crawl. Providing these pages share a general common theme, it can take a best guess on what kinds of ads to show on pages it has not crawled.